# I want to compile a libcurl program

Tags: c, linux, libcurl

I have the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>

int main() {
  printf("hello world\n");
  url_global_init( CURL_GLOBAL_ALL );
  CURL * myHandle;
  CURLcode result;
  myHandle = curl_easy_init();
  curl_easy_setopt( myHandle, CURLOPT_URL, "http://localhost");
  result = curl_easy_perform( myHandle );
  curl_easy_cleanup( myHandle );

  return 0;
}
```

I try to compile with
gcc source.c -lcurl

but unfortunately I get:
/tmp/ccIbuIzd.o: In function `main':
source.c:(.text+0xad): undefined reference to`url_global_init'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: how did you install the library? if by source, then you'll probably have to run `sudo ldconfig`

Comment: by source, I run ldconfig and nothing :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `url_global_init()` it's

```
curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_DEFAULT);
```

And you also need a `curl_global_cleanup()` at the end of the program.